# How do you describe polls based on their representativeness?

Tags: word-request

Some surveys have representational samples (they survey people of different ages, sexes, etc., and the subgroups are proportional) and those that do not (non-professional online polls, for instance). What do you call the former and the latter? 'Representational' and 'non-representational'? Maybe, 'sampled'/'non-sampled' or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would describe the surveys/polls as [biased](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/biased) and unbiased, respectively

> Giving results that are not accurate because information has not been collected correctly.

When the groups that are sampled are not proportional to their numbers in the population, the results of the survey/poll are going to be biased by that sampling. Of course, this assumes that the results are supposed to be representative of the population as a whole.